# Weird capturing behaviour in google re2

Tags: c++, regex, re2

Here's my code:

```
std::string captured;
if (RE2::PartialMatch("a b--b c", "(?:a b(?P<Contents>[^b]+)b)?", &captured)) {
    printf("match: %s\n", captured.c_str());
}
```

It prints:

```
match: --
```

As expected. Then I change first argument to to " a b--b c" (space added at the beginning). Now it prints:

```
match:
```

Wrong match. Is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not a bug as your regex can match an empty string. Since you only get 1 match, the empty string is returned. If you get all matches, you [will get the previous match](https://regex101.com/r/kU6tJ0/1), too.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Regex describes group Contents must be between 'b' characters. Why I get match with empty string? It is not between 'b's. regex101.com shows correct match for string with space at the beginning. Don't I get something?

Comment: The pattern says match something *optionally* because of `?` at the end. Thus, it matches each empty space before an unmatching character (with multiple matches).

Comment: Does this regex - [`(?:a b(?P<Contents>[^b]+)b)`](https://regex101.com/r/kU6tJ0/2) - answer your question?